# Can't access server on LAN new Router

Tags: networking, ssh, router

Earlier this week my roommates decided to change the router we are using for our home network. On the old router I had no problems accessing a laptop running Mint Linux over the network(SSH, FTP, and Shared Folders). However I am now not able to connect. I have verified the IP address of my Linux machine has not changed and I have no problems connecting to our NAS(WDMYCLOUD).

The new router is a D-Link DIR-868L. PuTTY is giving me a Timed Out error(was giving me a EHOSTUNREACH before). Running Windows 8.1 the connecting laptop, but tried connecting using my phone via SSH did not work either.

More information:
Can ping the Linux machine from the router but not my computer.

```
Pinging 192.168.0.111 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.102: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.102: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.102: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.102: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.111:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Comment: The problem is most likely that the IP address hasn't changed - that it is statically configured and the network address range changed when the router changed.  What is its IP address / netmask and yours?

Comment: The IP on my Linux machine is dynamic(though I should make it static). It is also within the valid range of IP addresses for the router. The IP for the linux machine is 192.168.0.111, while mine is 192.168.0.102. The subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: It looks like you aren't getting an arp response.  Can you ping the other way, from server to your computer?  Can you do an `arp -a` on both?

Comment: Cant ping either direction. Doing arp -a on my Linux Machine(server) only shows the router(IP: 192.168.0.1) in the list. My Windows Machine shows numerous entries(some dynamic lots of static). Running arp -a -v (verbose mode) shows my Linux machine has an invalid physical address(from my Windows machine). When run on the Linux Machine no change.

Comment: That is interesting.  It would seem like the switch in the router is not behaving as a switch in this case.  Did you by chance enable the DMZ mode in the router for the linux box?

Comment: Both are connected by WiFi if that makes any difference. And no I have not enabled DMZ mode(looked at it but it would not let me select either laptop) not that I think it would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16661/discussion-between-rmdan-and-paul).